# Why is the value of this uint32_t -2147483648?

Tags: c, binary, uint32

Using gcc compiler, why is this `uint32_t` -2147483648 when I set the MSB?  It's unsigned - shouldn't it be positive?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BIT_SET(a,b) ((a) |= (1<<(b)))

int main()
{
    uint32_t var = 0;
    BIT_SET(var, 31);

    printf("%d\n", var); //prints -2147483648

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of `var` is `uint32_t`. But you are printing it using `%d` which is *undefined behaviour*. Use `PRIu32` from `<inttypes.h>` to print `uint32_t`:

```
printf("%"PRIu32"\n",var);
```

Answer (score 7):

`%d` is for **signed** integers. What you want is `%u` which is for **unsigned** integers. `printf` is not *smart* enough to guess the type of your data.

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` doesn't know the type of something you pass it and has to **trust** you to use the correct *conversion specifier*. But you don't. With `%d`, `printf()` interprets your value as an `int`.

On a platform where `unsigned int` is the same as `uint32_t` (very common), you could use `%u` instead. But beware this isn't portable, e.g. to platforms where `int` only has 16 bits. The correct way to print an `uint32_t` looks like this (you have to include `inttypes.h`):

```
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", var);
```

See e.g. [this `inttypes.h` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using *wrong* format specifier here. `%d` is for `int` type, i.e, signed integer type.

To print exact width variables, you need to use `PRIuN` macros as format specifiers.

For unsigned type 32 bit, that would be `PRIu32`. For an exhaustive list, see chapter §7.8.1, `C11`.